# switch the value of variable javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two variables `M` & `N` and with certain condition in my loop I want to switch the value of `N` between itself and `M`. So the following code came in my mind

```
MxN = M * N;

N = MxN/N;
```

But values of `M` and `N` may be 2 000 000 000. Therefore Im in doubt. Is that fine variant to switch between such a huge values or may be its better(faster) to

```
counter = 2;
N = counter % 2 == 0 ? M : N; 
counter++;
```

**edit**
Sorry I didn't mention that I dont want to affect the value of M 
Thanks everyone)

Comment: You can't do "temp = M; M = N; N=temp;"? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: not to switch M with N but to switch N between N and M

Comment: @SakerONE Could you please add an example of input->output to your question?

Comment: input M = 3; N = 5; at first iteration of the loop N - 3 at second N - 5 at third N - 3 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways.

1 http://jsfiddle.net/8NvVf/

```
m -= n
n += m
m = n - m
```

2 http://jsfiddle.net/eQGwL/ (Only works in FireFox and maybe Rhino)

```
[n, m] = [m, n]
```

3 http://jsfiddle.net/4MQXe/

```
m = (n += m -= n) - m
```

### Edit

If you don't want to change the value of `m` you need a temp value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yjkn3/

```
var n = 5
var m = 8
var t = n

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    if(n != m) n = m
    else n = t
    console.log(n + ' ' + m)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that it was also to do such swap trick using arrays in Javascript. Is that a new language feature or something that existed "since the beginning"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I dont want to affect the value of M

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches are suspect to an integer overflow (and the earlier one also to precision errors). Why not limit the range of the counter and adapt the second approach?

```
state = 0;
switch (state) {
case 0:
    // ...
    break;
case 1:
    // ...
    break;
// ...
}

state = state < maxState ? state + 1 : 0;
```

It is up to you to optimize this, but please keep readability and maintainability in mind. An alternative to this `switch` is to use an array.

For two variables, please do not mess with `xor` hacks when trying to swap variables, just write what you want:

```
var temp = N;
N = M;
M = N;
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic trick for swapping two values is to use XOR:

```
x = x xor y
y = x xor y
x = x xor y
```